# Fix keyboard orientation in landscape iPad app (upside down keyboard)

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard, orientation, landscape

I'm converting a landscape (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) iPhone app to be a universal app.  So far I've got the orientation working properly: the iPad version will launch with the right splash graphic and start in the right orientation (LandscapeLeft or LandscapeRight) depending on how the user is holding it.

But: when I trigger the keyboard while the iPad is in LandscapeLeft, the keyboard appears upside down:

I can't post images yet so you can see the error here:
http://blog.durdle.com/images/ipad_keyboard.png

That's a UIAlertView with a UITextField added to it.  I guess the keyboard at this point is in the LandscapeRight orientation.

If I rotate the device to LandscapeRight, the game view rotates to match the keyboard, then if I rotate the device back to LandscapeLeft the entire interface - game AND keyboard rotate together to appear correctly.

So: how do I ensure it appears in the correct orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops.  Boy do I feel foolish.

I'd left this code in the method that opens my UIAlertView:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
```

Which was a holdover from the original iPhone app when I needed to force the keyboard orientation in OS 2.2.1.  It's now entirely unnecessary!  Removing it has fixed the problem.